# Xcode 7.2 Cordova 4.2 Archive failed "Cordova/CDVViewController not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I m facing error while making an archive for *Appstore* release. Although i have added

```
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

in my Project's header search path.

Application builds perfectly fine while running on device and simulator.

Now Header search path is like:

```
"$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"      
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" 
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" 
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

Please help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem by adding this 

`"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"` 
in only Release Header Search Path option in `Build Settings` of my Project.

Now Its archiving without any Build Error.